# Cyclic Map in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to construct a recursive data structure, but I'm having some problems. I'm currently implementing a type system, and I'm trying to implement recursive types. So, I wanted to have actual infinite type structures, that can be recursive, using OCaml's type constructors. This is my attempt at minimizing the issue down as much as I can with the error still occurring.

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

type ty = 
  | TyRecord of (ty StringMap.t)

let rec recursive_ty =
  let rec temp = lazy (
    TyRecord (StringMap.singleton "self" (Lazy.force temp))
  ) in
  Lazy.force temp
```

And the error `Exception: CamlinternalLazy.Undefined` occurs when executing the expression for `recursive_ty`.

Basically, I'm trying to construct a cyclic `ty StringMap.t`. I want to be able to do this **without enabling `-rectypes`**, especially since the type of `recursive_ty` is not recursive, it should just be `ty`. I know that the following works just fine:

```
type ty = 
  | TyRecord of (string * ty) list

let rec recursive_ty = TyRecord [("self", recursive_ty)]
```

but I want to use a `StringMap` for efficiently searching the keys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the constructor lazy, e.g.,

```
type ty = TyRecord of ty StringMap.t Lazy.t
let rec t = TyRecord (lazy (StringMap.singleton "self" t));;
```

Alternatively, you can use a thunk.